# Mysqlbackup error using MysqlBackup 2.0.4

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-backup

im trying to back up my database with the code below using mysqlBackUp 2.0.4

```
private void button9_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string constring = "Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=sulyman;database=accounting_db";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                string file = "D:\\backup.sql";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                dal.Open();
                MySqlBackup ba = new MySqlBackup(cmd);
                ba.ExportToFile(file);
                dal.close();
                MessageBox.Show("done");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }


        }
```

but i got the error

```
a object reference note set to an instance of an object
```

at the line

```
 ba.ExportToFile(file);
```

where is the wrong with my code please

Comment: Why you kept `MySqlCommand cmd;` declaration outside of this method? And what is `dal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: Seems like DB connection is not open or you are using `dal.Open()` instead of `conn.Open()`.

1. I have commented `dal.Open();`, `dal.Close();` and added `conn.Open();`
2. Delcared `MySqlCommand` inside method.
3. Added `using` statement

Try this code:

```
private void button9_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string constring = "Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=sulyman;database=accounting_db";
            string file = "D:\\backup.sql";
            using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))                
            using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open(); //dal.Open();
                using(MySqlBackup ba = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                   ba.ExportToFile(file);
                   //dal.close();
                   MessageBox.Show("done");
                }
            }

        catch(Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }
```

Comment: yes that is right.i corrected it while u r writing the solution
dal is my connection class and i used to use it to open and close the connection but here im using defferent connection
thanks very much Hassan Nisar